# Meaning of a state breaking e.g. $\rm U(1)$ symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, symmetry-breaking

I am reading a paper in which the authors discuss many-body states and describe them in terms of their symmetries, but do not know what is meant by e.g. a state breaking $U(1)$ symmetry.

The symmetries are stated in terms of which single-particle states are occupied, and these have the labels orbital $n=0,1$, valley $\alpha=K,K^′$, and spin $s=↑,↓$. (Another label, $k$, is not relevant here.) Hence, the creation operators are written as $c_{n\alpha sk}^+$. For example, they write that the state which mixes only spins
$$
\prod_k \bigg( \left(\cos \psi c_{0 K \uparrow k}^{+}+\sin \psi c_{0 K \downarrow k}^{+}\right)\left(\cos \psi c_{0 K' \uparrow k}^{+}-\sin \psi c_{0 K' \downarrow k}^{+}\right)\left(\cos \psi c_{1 K \uparrow k}^{+}+\sin \psi c_{1 K \downarrow k}^{+}\right)\left(\cos \psi c_{1 K' \uparrow k}^{+}-\sin \psi c_{1 K' \downarrow k}^{+}\right) \bigg)|\varnothing\rangle \tag{1}
$$
breaks a $U(1)$ symmetry in spin sector for $ψ≠0,π/2$, while e.g. for $ψ=0$ it breaks no symmetries; i.e. the state
$$
\prod_{k}\left(c_{0 K \uparrow k}^{+} c_{0 K^{\prime} \uparrow k}^{+} c_{1 K \uparrow k}^{+} c_{1 K^{\prime} \uparrow k}^{+}\right)|\emptyset\rangle \tag{2}
$$
breaks no symmetries. Likewise, they write that the spin=valley-mixing state
$$
\prod_{k}\left(c_{0 K \uparrow k}^{+}\left(\cos \psi c_{0 K \downarrow k}^{+}+\sin \psi c_{0 K^{\prime} \uparrow k}^{+}\right) c_{1 K \uparrow k}^{+}\left(\cos \psi c_{1 K \downarrow k}^{+}+\sin \psi c_{1 K^{\prime} \uparrow k}^{+}\right)\right)|\varnothing\rangle \tag{3}
$$
breaks a $U(1)$ symmetry which is a combination of spin and valley.

Clearly, the superpositions are what break the symmetries - I can recognize the pattern. However, I do not understand why this description applies. $U(1)$ is just the group of unit-modulus complex numbers, i.e. phase.

My best guess is that the authors are referring to applying the group elements of $U(1)$ to the single-particle states, or creation operators $c_{n\alpha sk}^+$. In that case, states $(1)$ and $(2)$ would be changed, as the phase of the superpositions would change - for example, sending $c_{0 K \uparrow k}^{+} \rightarrow e^{i\phi} c_{0 K \uparrow k}^{+}$ changes the phase of the superposition in (1), and hence changes the many-particle state, whereas the same substitution in (2) just multiplies the entire many-particle state by a phase and hence does not change it. Is the correct idea? Where can I find this discussed and explained more completely?

For context, [here is the paper I am reading](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.02447), and the states are listed in Sec. IV in the form of a matrix.